# Conditional reshape based on leading characters

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a two column data frame `x`:

```
case_num <- c("ABC-01", "111 XX", "ABC-02", "111 XX", "Y32 XX", "113 XX",
              "ABC-03", "112 XX", "Z90 XX")
transac_num <- c("DEF-01", NA, "DEF-02", NA, NA, NA, "DEF-03", NA, NA)

x <- data.frame(case_num, transac_num)

case_num    transac_num
ABC-01      DEF-01
111 XX       
ABC-02      DEF-02
111 XX      
Y32 XX
113 XX
ABC-03      DEF-03
112 XX
Z90 XX
```

I'd like reshape the dataset so that all rows that do **not** begin with "ABC" are put into separate columns on the same row as the `case_num` just above them, while rows that begin with "ABC" are kept where they are. The desired output is:

```
case_num  transac_num     charge1    charge2    charge3
ABC-01    DEF-01          111 XX
ABC-02    DEF-02          111 XX     Y32 XX     113 XX
ABC-03    DEF-03          112 XX     Z90 XX
```

I tried to accomplish this by first creating a new column that specifies whether `case_number` is a case or a charge, using the `transac_num` field:

```
x$type <- ifelse(is.na(x$transac_num), "charge", "case")
```

Which results in

```
case_num    transac_num    type
ABC-01      DEF-01         case
111 XX                     charge
ABC-02      DEF-02         case
111 XX                     charge
Y32 XX                     charge
113 XX                     charge
ABC-03      DEF-03         case
112 XX                     charge
Z90 XX                     charge
```

But I can't get tidyr's `pivot_wider` to create new columns from `case_num`  only on the condition `x$type == "charge"`. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `fill` to fill the NA elements with the previous non-NA values, `slice` out the first row, after grouping by 'transac_num', create a column name column based on the sequence from 'transac_num' and use `pivot_wider` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
x %>%
    fill(transac_num) %>% 
    group_by(transac_num) %>%
    slice(-1) %>%
    mutate(new_col = str_c('charge', rowid(transac_num))) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from =new_col, values_from = case_num)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   transac_num [3]
#  transac_num charge1 charge2 charge3
#  <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 ABC-01      111 XX  <NA>    <NA>   
#2 ABC-02      111 XX  Y32 XX  113 XX 
#3 ABC-03      112 XX  Z90 XX  <NA>
```

---

If we want to keep another column, create the new column after doing the group by

```
x %>%
    fill(transac_num) %>%
    group_by(transac_num) %>% 
    mutate(case_num_orig = first(case_num)) %>%
    slice(-1) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    select(case_num_new = case_num, case_num = case_num_orig, transac_num) %>%
    mutate(new_col = str_c('charge', rowid(transac_num))) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = new_col, values_from = case_num_new)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  case_num transac_num charge1 charge2 charge3
#  <chr>    <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 ABC-01   DEF-01      111 XX  <NA>    <NA>   
#2 ABC-02   DEF-02      111 XX  Y32 XX  113 XX 
#3 ABC-03   DEF-03      112 XX  Z90 XX  <NA>
```

Comment: For me, this doesn't quite generate the desired output: the `case_num` field should be preserved, and charges just below each `case_num` should appear on the same row. Instead, the `transac_num` field is preserved (in some cases `case_num` and `transac_num` will differ; edited my example), and the `charge` rows are still beneath the `case` rows.

Comment: @hoho I checked your desired output and it is showing the same output as this

Comment: Thank you. I edited the desired output after your first answer to include both `case_num` and `transac_num` columns. Is there a way to preserve the `case_num` field as well? I tried adding `case_num` to  `group_by`, but the `slice` function removes the `case_num` ID row.